# Exchange Server - How to use existing certificate without CSR?

Tags: exchange-2010, ssl-certificate

I have some SSL certificates problem.

We have an Exchange 2010 server hosting mailboxes for mydomain.com, otherdomain.com and thirddomain.com. It's internal name is myserver.mydomain.local.

When setup, it came with its self-signed certificate on the name "myserver".

We already have an SSL certificate for mail.mydomain.com (containing the SAN mydomain.com), and want to use it so everyone will connect to OWA / Activesync / Outlook Anywhere etc. using the url : mail.mydomain.com.

The only resources I find searching the web are telling me to create a certificate request using the Exchange MMC, then forward it to the CA to issue a new certificate then complete the request on the Exchange server.

But how can I re-use our existing certificate ? It is fine, it has already the good server names in it, we don't want to re-pay for a new certificate ! (also we should pay for revoking the old one before a new one could be issued).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the certificate (with private key) on the Exchange Server in the Computer's Personal Store. Then you can select it in Exchange

Comment: You pointed me the right way : "with private key". I had two separate files for certificate and private key. I merged then using openssl command line (see [http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25996/how-to-import-a-private-key-in-windows]), and then I was able to import it into Exchange MMC and use it for the services. Now that's right !